# Need an Excel formula for sum the values of same cells with special rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to sum the cells that have the same name in another cells & same agreement in another cells again.

Example: sum value in "E" that has the same name in "A" & has an agreement sign in "D"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) or [SUMIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA102753226.aspx?CTT=1) function.